# Update claims in asp.net claim based authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, claims-based-identity

I have an asp.net application, for authentication i use claim based authentication. By default asp stores the user's claims in a cookie(i think).

I have an admin panel, admin can change user's claims. For example user A has "CRUD" Claims (for ClaimType = "Document"), admin decides to change "CRUD" to "CRU" (D is omitted).

User has "CRUD" claims until his cookie is expired, because he logged in before admin's decision.

how can we force user's cookie to be updated to have "CRU" claims.